# Read Access Violation. _Mem was nullptr while assigning QString after calling HeapAlloc()

Tags: c++, windows, qt, memory

I have a program that is using `HeapAlloc()` to allocate a struct that contains a `QString` and a few `QByteArray` structs.

Struct code:

```
struct Environment {
    QString internalLinksDomain;
    QByteArray aboutTelegram;
    QByteArray aboutContacts;
    QByteArray aboutFrequent;
    QByteArray aboutSessions;
    QByteArray aboutWebSessions;
    QByteArray aboutChats;
    QByteArray aboutLeftChats;
};
```

My code:

```
Environment* e = (Environment*)HeapAlloc(GetProcessHeap(), HEAP_ZERO_MEMORY, sizeof(Environment));

e->internalLinksDomain = "Test data";
```

I have also tried..

```
e->internalLinksDomain.append("Test data");
```

Both send me to the `atomic` file in Visual Studio. I have attached a screen shot of the error and its position in the function causing the error.

[VS Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u4auI.png)

Comment: `Environment* e = (Environment*)HeapAlloc(GetProcessHeap(), HEAP_ZERO_MEMORY, sizeof(Environment));` is not going to call the constructor on any of the `QString`  or `QByteArray` members.

Comment: Related: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/222557/what-uses-are-there-for-placement-new](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/222557/what-uses-are-there-for-placement-new)

Comment: If I created the struct normally like ```Environment e``` and then did ```e.internalLinksDomain = "test";``` would that call the constructor?

Comment: Yes without HeapAlloc() the constructor would be called correctly. With my second comment you can fix it to work with HeapAlloc() but I question the why you want to use this over using new.

Comment: I am not sure how to do it using new. I am learning C++ and the link mentioned above is beyond my current knowledge.

Comment: Only fix for that is to go back a to earlier material until you understand what's going on and work your way forward again. C++ is not a good language to jump around in while learning. Boobytraps galore.

Comment: Actually I think I figured it out. I just need to create a constructor in the struct that accepts arguments that I set to the struct members.